# creating a login page this is the error

Tags: mysql, xampp

[Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pomelo\dbconnect.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pomelo\dbconnect.php on line 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPZX.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to images of your code. Edit your question to include the code directly. Also please describe more clearly what the problem is, where it occurs and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes first. It would be better to paste your code into the question instead of linking to an image. Also I'd remove the sql tag and add php instead, as that's where you're problem is.

What version of PHP are you using? According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), that function has been deprecated since 5.5 and replaced with mysqli_real_escape_string()